# Grafana Range Value Mapping Issue

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I am trying to set my grafana gauge panel using the range value mapping.

I want to set for the valye 1-31 will be return as good and 31 above to not good.

[image]

But I tried and it did not change. Not sure why?

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the visualization to gauge

Comment: Answers should be more elaborated and should exactly address the problem asked.